# Local Users and Groups in Windows10 Home upgrade

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

To add a new user and group in Windows 10 Home
I tried to do it using lusrmgr.msc on Run. Which works for many, but for my version of Windows10, I am able to add users only through control panel.
[Computer Management Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3ic8.png)  ,error message: local users and groups this snapin may not be used with this edition of windows 10
I did find a fix, but it is  applicable only for Pro and Enterprise editions of Windows.
[link for Fix](http://www.kapilarya.com/this-snap-in-may-not-be-used-with-this-edition-of-windows)
I also see that we can use control panel, but that is not best way, because I wanted to add groups, please explain if we can use control panel to do it.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please edit your question.

Comment: I wanted to add a user to Local users and groups, but I am unable because of some new windows update, there is a fix but that is limited for few versions of windows

Comment: If you want that capability you will have to upgrade to Windows 10 Professional, Education, or Enterprise.  Windows 10 Home has never had access to `lusrmgr.msc`

Comment: Thanks for information @Ramhound , will work on how to upgrade, your suggestions are most welcome

Comment: How you upgrade from Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Prodessional is well document.  What step are you stuck on?

Comment: I don't have a home edition but try to run PowerShell as an administrator and then run: `New-LocalGroup -Name "MyGroup"` and `Add-LocalGroupMember -Group MyGroup -Member username`, or even you can use the old `net localgroup` command

Comment: @Ramhound I did upgrade to Windows10 Enterprise, thanks for your time

Comment: @PeterHahndorf - You didn't have Windows 10 Professional, you never said what version you had, the fact you couldn't use the applet told me what you didn't have.  Windows 10 Single Language is basically Windows 10 Home.

Answer (score 12):

You can add new user in windows 10 with help of the following method,

1. Windows Key + R
2. Type "netplwiz" without quotes
3. Press Enter
4. In "Users" tab click on "Add..."
5. Follow the instruction. You can add local user or a microsoft account
6. After adding user then click on "Advanced" tab
7. And change the group of the added user into user or administrator

other way to press windows logo + R and type control userpasswords2 in the run box, then press enter and it will take the same place to the above mentioned users tab.

Comment: This works like a charm. Too bad it isn't easier to find in Windows 10.

Comment: I can't see a way to edit a local user's group membership or other advanced settings that are only exposed in the Local Users and Groups snap-in - while software is still free to install itself and create its own users and groups (looking at you, NVIDIA). This is only going to cost Microsoft in user-frustration IT techs being unable to clean-up poorly written software.

Comment: netplwiz and userpasswords2 won't work on Windows 10 Home Edition, you're left with CLI tools on cmd and Powershell on that edition.

Comment: `netplwiz` is hardly usable on Windows 10 Home (21H1) - when going into the advanced mode you will see the error _This snapin may not be used with this edition of Windows 10. To manage user accounts for this computer, use the User Account tool in the Control Panel._

Answer (score 3):

Following 2nd part of @Peter Hahndorf's comment, namely:

> ...you can use the old `net localgroup` command

Is IMHO the easiest way to fix it on Windows 10 Home:

> `net localgroup groupname username /add`

*Where username is the name of the existing user you want to add and groupname is the name of the group you want to add them to.* Source: [Net_(command)/Localgroup](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Net_(command)/Localgroup)

Answer (score 2):

@Peter Hahndorf's comment is straight on the target when he says you could use Powershell to tackle the issue:

> I don't have a home edition but try to run PowerShell as an administrator and then run: `New-LocalGroup -Name "MyGroup"` and `Add-LocalGroupMember -Group MyGroup -Member username`, or even you can use the old `net localgroup` command

I've met this problem over a trivial thing: my new notebook came with W10 Home Edition. I had previously purchased W10 Pro but didn't want to reinstall everything because Xbox Game Bar won't show my FPS count.

You can manually do it with the command `Add-LocalGroupMember`, just like Peter said, or you can use a simple loop on Get-LocalGroup, like this:

```
Get-LocalGroup | ForEach-Object {
    if ( $_.Name -like '*performance*' ) {
        Add-LocalGroupMember -Group $_.Name -Member $Env:USERNAME
    }
}
```

Mind you, the string `'*performance*'` is regional. In my case, with pt-br system, I had to switch it to "desempenho". Run, logoff and logon, and everything looks as it should. Powershell just saved me once again, this time from reinstalling a proper W10 edition.

Comment: It's OK to build an answer on somebody else's comment (as long as you give credit to the source, which you did), but you should make your answer self-contained / self-sufficient.   If Peter Hahndorf's comment is deleted, your answer will not make much sense.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to improve it!

Answer (score 0):

Run PowerShell as an administrator and run the command to add a particular user to a particular user group (will work in Home Edition):

```
Add-LocalGroupMember docker-users DESKTOP-123XXX\MyAccountName
```

To find the list of users:

```
Get-LocalUser
```

And to get your computer name:

```
hostname
```