# Make my shared folder visible only to a certain user on second PC

Tags: windows-10, network-shares

I have a folder on my Win10 Desktop, which I want to be shared on network, but only be accessible by a certain one user on a second computer.

I tried it in Advanced Sharing options of the file, but I can find only users on my PC.

Comment: If you aren't on an ActiveDirectory network, the windows box sharing the folder has no way to know about other users or machines on your network. You need to give the second computer user their own user account on the first computer.  Then add that new user to the shared folder for access.

Comment: I'm not on ActiveDirectory network. I added the other user as family member in Windows settings and gave the permission to read/write, I can map the folder as network folder on the second PC, but I can't open it.

Comment: To see your ACTUAL users and groups, use [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1108565/local-users-and-groups-in-windows10-home-upgrade) post. and add a simple user there. Make sure the user is is valid (on the sharing machine) by logging in locally with it.  When the second machine connects, IT should get a request for logon with user / password.  ***User***: <sharing_pc_name>\<sharing_pc_user> ***Password:*** <sharing_user_account_password>